# Python Monty Hall Simulation didn't give expected answer

Tags: python, logic, simulation

I get the answer 0.5 in the Monty Hall Simulation.

From the textbook: We assume the car was put behind a door by rolling a three-sided die which made all three choices equally likely. Monty knows where the car is, and always opens a door with a goat behind it. Finally, we assume that if Monty has a choice of doors (i.e., the contestant has picked the door with the car behind it),he chooses each door with probability 1/2. Marilyn clearly expected her readers to assume that the game was played in this manner.

Marilyn's answer is 0.66, and I want to simulate this answer, but I got 0.5 and don't know what's wrong with my codes.

```
n = 1000000
count = 0
for i in range(n):
    doors = [1,2,3]  
    # the inital doors that monty can choose
    monty_choose = [1,2,3]
    # suppose the car is behind door 1
    car = 1   
    # monty cannot choose the door that has car
    monty_choose.remove(car)    
    ichoose = random.choice(doors)  
    if ichoose in monty_choose:
        # monty cannot choose the door i select
        monty_choose.remove(ichoose)  
        monty = random.choice(monty_choose)  
    else:
        monty = random.choice(monty_choose)
    # i cannot choose the door that monty chose  
    doors.remove(monty)   
    s = random.choice(doors)
    if s == car:
        count = count + 1 
print(count/n)
```

Comment: What makes you think that the answer should be `0.66`?

Comment: code is hard to understand - for ex. you define `monty_choose` both outside and inside the loop

Comment: i'd also suggest put comments on their own lines, instead of just adding them on at the end.

Comment: From the book Introduction of Probability, the Monty Hall problem. We assume that the car was put behind a door by rolling a three-sided die which made all three choices equally likely. Monty knows where the car is, and always opens a door with a goat behind it. Moreover, we assume that if Monty has
a choice of doors (i.e., the contestant has picked the door with the car behind it),
he chooses each door with a probability 1/2. That is what Marilyn thought and her answer is 0.66(2/3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code could work find until you get to the last bit. You are picking the door at random:

```
 s = random.choice(doors)
    if s == car:
        count = count + 1
```

When what you want to do is to switch doors. You can do this by simply removing your first choice then indexing the list at 0.

```
    doors.remove(ichoose)
    
    if doors[0] == car:
        count = count + 1
```

full code and result

```
import random

n = 1000000
count = 0
for i in range(n):
    doors = [1,2,3]  
    # the inital doors that monty can choose
    monty_choose = [1,2,3]
    # suppose the car is behind door 1
    car = 1   
    # monty cannot choose the door that has car
    
    monty_choose.remove(car)    
    ichoose = random.choice(doors)  
    if ichoose in monty_choose:
        # monty cannot choose the door i select
        monty_choose.remove(ichoose) 
        monty = random.choice(monty_choose)
    else:
        monty = random.choice(monty_choose)
    # i cannot choose the door that monty chose  
    doors.remove(monty)  
    
    
    doors.remove(ichoose)
    
    if doors[0] == car:
        count = count + 1 
        
        
print(count/n)
0.667145
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code calculates probability of `0.5` simply because `s = random.choice(doors)` is choosing from car or goat equally.

Your code does not reflect how the Monty Hall problem works.

If the contestant makes a choice and sticks with that choice, then the probability is obviously `0.33`. You never allow `ichoose` to stick with their choice.

The less obvious part is that the contestant can change their choice and then the probability is `0.66`. You never allow `ichoose` to change their choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

doors = [1,2,3]  # total doors
i_choose = [1,2,3] # the inital doors that I can choose
car = 1   # suppose the car is behind door 1
host_choose = [2,3] # the empty doors the host could show
n = 10000000
count = 0
car = 1
always_change= True # player strategy
for i in range(n):
    # you can randomize car here, but remember to change host_choose accordingly
    first_choice = random.choice(doors) # I choose one door randomly
    if first_choice in host_choose:
        host_choose.remove(first_choice) # the host cannot open the chosen door
    host_choice = random.choice(host_choose) # the host shows that a door is empty
    i_choose.remove(host_choice)
    if always_change:
        i_choose.remove(first_choice)
        # the goal is to show that always changing door results in 66% winrate
        i_choice = random.choice(i_choose) # this is actually a one-element list
    else:
        i_choice = first_choice
    if i_choice == car:
        count = count + 1
    i_choose = [1,2,3]
    doors = [1,2,3]
    host_choose = [2,3]
print(count/n)
```

---

So basically, you're mixing up who and when does the choices:

1. A picks a door in [1, 2, 3]
2. B knows where the car is, and reveals an empty door (that A didn't pick)
3. A now can choose to keep their door or to change it

Your goal is to show that changing door leads to 0.66 probability of getting the car.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! However, I am wondering why Monty can choose first because according to the textbook, the contestant (I) should choose first, and then Monty chooses the door that is left and doesn't have a car behind.

Comment: Yeah, A (or i in the code) is the contestant, A makes a choice, then Monty (B) shows one empty door and asks if the contestant would like to change their choice. If the contestant always keeps the first choice you get ~0.33, if the contestant always changes you get ~0.66